# Algolia autocomplete: How do I highlight items?

Tags: search, autocomplete, highlight, algolia

I use Algolia autocomplete in "standalone" mode, meaning without the commercial Algolia service to return the search results; I have my own server respond with an array of search results.

How do I highlight matches in my returned items/strings (search results)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend must return results that are already highlighted using a tag such as: `<mark>this-is-to-be-highlighted</mark>`. Here's an example result array for an search for "pie":

```js
const items = [
  { some_attribute: 'Apple <mark>pie</mark>' },
  { some_attribute: 'American <mark>pie</mark>' },
  { some_attribute: 'Chocolate <mark>pie</mark>' }
]
```

The complete javascript code would then be something like this:

```js
import { autocomplete } from "@algolia/autocomplete-js"


autocomplete({
  container: '#search_input',

  // ...

  getSources({ query }) {

    // This would be an example response from your server
    const items = [
      { some_attribute: 'Apple <mark>pie</mark>' },
      { some_attribute: 'American <mark>pie</mark>' },
      { some_attribute: 'Chocolate <mark>pie</mark>' }
    ]

    return [

      {
        sourceId: 'pies',

        getItems({ query }) {
          const HIGHLIGHT_PRE_TAG = '__aa-highlight__'
          const HIGHLIGHT_POST_TAG = '__/aa-highlight__'

          return items.map((item) => ({
            item,
            _highlightResult: {
              some_attribute: {
                value: item.some_attribute
                  .replace(/<mark>/g, HIGHLIGHT_PRE_TAG)
                  .replace(/<\/mark>/g, HIGHLIGHT_POST_TAG)
              }
            }
          }))
        },

        templates: {

          // ...

          item({ item, components, html }) {
            return html`<div className="aa-ItemWrapper">
              <div className="aa-ItemContent">
                <div className="aa-ItemContentBody">
                  <div className="aa-ItemContentTitle">
                    ${components.Highlight({ hit: item, attribute: 'some_attribute' })}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>`
          },

          // ...

        }
      },

      // ...

    ]

  },

  // ...

})
```